# Cannot install rsync (unable to create...Input/output error)

Tags: linux, rsync, dpkg

How do I resolve the following error to get `rsync` installed?

`unable to create '/usr/bin/rsync.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/rsync'): Input/output error`

Full log follows:

```
ubuntu@explorer:~$ uname -a
Linux explorer 3.8.2-g659a590 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 24 02:38:40 PDT 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

ubuntu@explorer:~$ sudo apt-get install rsync
sudo: unable to resolve host explorer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rsync
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/282 kB of archives.
After this operation, 516 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 27315 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking rsync (from .../rsync_3.0.9-4_armhf.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/rsync_3.0.9-4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/bin/rsync.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/bin/rsync'): Input/output error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/rsync_3.0.9-4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running [Linux for Tegra](https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-tegra).

Comment: My first guess would be a disk I/O error. Check dmesg: `dmesg | tail -30`

Comment: Thanks, I added it as an answer. I didn't add it as an answer originally because I didn't think it would turn out to be something so obvious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of the *Input/Output Error* would be an actual disk I/O error.

See if the kernel is reporting any disk I/O errors or filesystem errors by looking at the recent entries in your dmesg kernel log buffer:

`dmesg | tail -30`

Comment: Yup, this turned out to be the problem. Something was wrong with the file system. Whenever I tried to install `rsync` it would fail as the above and output: `EXT3-fs error (device foobar) in ext3_new_inode: IO failure`